# How come it does not do a loop in my Python code

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. I tried the following code. However, I cannot figure out how come it does not do a "for" loop in my function.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import tarfile
from IPython.display import display, Image
from scipy import ndimage
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle

def checkOverlap( sample, setToTest):
errorThresh = 0.0001
dataShape = setToTest.shape
numOfIms = dataShape[0]
print('Number of arrays:' numOfIms)
#How come it does not do the following loop?
for idx2 in range(numOfIms):
    print('Iteration: ',idx2)
    im = setToTest[idx2,:,:]
    err = np.subtract(sample,im)
    errAbs = np.abs(err)
    maxErr = np.max(errAbs)
    if maxErr < errorThresh:
        # print('Image Idx: ', idx,' is overlapping image with maxErr = ', maxErr)
        plt.figure(3)
        plt.imshow(errAbs)
        plt.draw()
        return True, idx2
    else:
        # print('Image Idx: ', idx,' is not overlapping image with maxErr = ', maxErr)
        return False, idx2

setToTest= np.ndarray((10,2,2), dtype=np.int32)
sample = np.ndarray((2,2), dtype = np.int32)
checkOverlap(sample,setToTest)
```

The output is just as follows:

Number of arrays: 10

Iteration: 0

Could you please let me know what I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you reformat your code ?

Comment: You return inside the loop, so of course it's going to do one iteration and then it's done.

Comment: There is a return whether `maxErr < errorThresh` is true or false, so only one iteration.

Comment: Please [edit] your code block to fix the indentation.  There should be 4 leading spaces on each line, plus whatever indentation the Python code already had.  See the Help Center's guide to [Markdown syntax for code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Because you return during the first iteration itself, no matter what. I think you should rethink your logic and remove the return statements from the if..else first.

Answer (score 1):

You have an if, else statement in the middle of your loop, each of which has a return statement. This means that your loop will only be run once then you will return a value, halting the loop.